# Entity Framework 7: get database time

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

What is the best method to get the database server time in EF7? I discovered so far that is currently no support for query with output parameters.

Comment: Can you add more details? e.g. sample code, articles you have read, etc. It is hard to tell what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done using ADO.NET approach:

```
public DateTime GetServerUtcNow()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_settings.ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "select SYSUTCDATETIME()";
        return (DateTime)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use Entity Framework, you can do it like that:

- Having this context:

  ```
  // My Dbcontext
  public class EF7Context : DbContext { }
  ```
- And the utility function:

  ```
  public static DateTime GetDbDateTime()
  {
      using (var context = new EF7Context())
      {
          using (var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection())
          {
              if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
              {
                  connection.Open();
              }

              var command = connection.CreateCommand();
              command.CommandText = "select SYSUTCDATETIME()";
              return (DateTime)command.ExecuteScalar();
          }
      }
  }
  ```