# EntityFrameworkCore, trying to execute raw sql query but get error: "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open."

Tags: entity-framework, database-connection, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I need to run a raw sql query, but I'm getting an error when I try to open the connection to the database. *"The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open."*

_loginValidator and _contactService are passed into the controller through DI:

```
services.AddScoped<ILoginValidator, LoginValidator>();
services.AddScoped<IContactService, ContactService>();
```

The two lines below are in an action function of the controller. **If I switch the two lines, the error goes away...**:

```
var validationErrors = _loginValidator.Validate(id, ""); 

var user = _contactService.GetContact(id);
```

Here is _loginValidator.Validate. **If I comment out the second line, the error goes away...**:

```
public LoginValidationResult Validate(int userId, string encryptedPassword)
{
    var vr = new LoginValidationResult();

    var user = _context.Users.Include(u => u.LoginUserQuestionAnswers).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);

    //...
}
```

Here is _contactService.GetContact. **This is where I get the error**:

```
public ContactDto GetContact(int id)
{
    var conn = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();

    //ERROR HERE!!!
    conn.Open();

    //work on conn, for example: ExecuteReader

    conn.Close();
}
```

Notes:

- If I comment out the _context line in the Validate(...) function, I do not get the error.
- If I switch the two lines I listed in the action function, I do not get the error.

I think the problem is that EntityCore is not closing the connection after I finish using it in _loginValidator.Validate(...)

Anyone know how I can deal with this problem?

Comment: Where do you close the connection?

Answer (score 0):

DB Connection is an unmanaged resource and you need to close it yourself. The best practice is to use a **using** statement for your DB connections. 
See these links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077000/entity-framework-7-get-database-time

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456849.aspx

Comment: When EF opens a connection for you, then it should close it when done. This is not happening in this case, which is a bug in EF: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6581

Answer (score 0):

The connection being left open after the FirstOrDefault query is a bug. I filed https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6581 for it and we just triaged it for the 1.0.2 release.

To workaround the bug for now I think you can check if the connection is already open and, if so, don't try to open it again.