# Entity Framework get sysdate from DUAL of Oracle

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

What is the best approach to get SYSDATE from 'DUAL' of Oracle?

I tried to use ExecuteSqlRawAsync but I need return value as well.

```
public async Task<DateTime> GetTime()
{
  // This does not return value and does not work
  await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("Select sysdate from dual;");
}
```

Another way is to create a modelbuilder like.

```
public partial class Dual 
{
  public DateTime SysDate { get; set; }
}

public virtual DbSet<Dual> Dual { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Entity<Dual>(e => { ... });
```

And use the query.

```
await _dbContext.Dual.FromSqlRaw("Select sysdate from dual;").ToListAsync();
```

Is there any simpler or better approach to get 'SYSDATE' from Oracle? I am using EF Core version 5.

Comment: `_dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select sysdate from dual")
                            .FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: This approach does not work for EF 3 and higher.

Comment: Docs- Entity Framework- Entity Framework 6 -Query data -Use raw SQL queries    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql

`context.Database.SqlQuery<string>`

Comment: _dbContext,Database is DatabaseFacade, so the method SqlQuery is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the solution mentioned in this thread:

[Entity Framework 7: get database time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077000/entity-framework-7-get-database-time)

```
public async Task<DateTime> GetTime()
{
    DbConnection connection = _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();
    }

    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "select sysdate from dual";
    return (DateTime) await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if there are any other better approaches but this one works as well.